# Inherit a data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Is is possible to inherit a data type in haskell? Lets assume that:

```
data Data1 = Data1
    { name :: String
    } deriving (Show)
```

On the same module, i want to do something like:

```
data Data2 = Data1 
let x = Data2 "Something"
```

I wish that `Data2` has the field `name`, 'inherited' from `Data1`.

I know that `data Data2 = Data1` doesn't do that. So, I want to know if there is a way to do it.

thanks

Andre

Comment: I just wanted to point out that [Vinyl](https://github.com/VinylRecords/Vinyl/blob/master/Data/Vinyl/Relation.hs) records do have something like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell doesn't have inheritance. In fact, banish all OOP related thoughts from your mind.

Instead, thinking in terms of composition is a more fruitful approach.

```
newtype Data1 = Data1 {name :: String}
              deriving Show

newtype Data2 = Data2 {wrappedD1 :: String}
```

Now you could have

```
nameD2 :: Data2 -> String
nameD2 = name . wrappedD1
```

However, if you want to use the same name for both these operations, you'd want "ad-hoc polymorphism" aka overloading. In Haskell land we have typeclasses for this

```
data D1 = D1 {nameD1 :: String} deriving Show
data D2 = D2 {wrappedD1 :: D1} deriving Show

class Named a where
  name :: a -> String

instance Named Data1 where
 name = nameD1
instance Named Data2 where
  name = name . wrappedD1
```

Now we can use `name` on both `D1` and `D2`. This is similar to the concept of an interface.

Tangent: You use the toplevel syntax `let foo = bar` but in Haskell, we only use `let` bindings in GHCi due to a weird quirk of how GHCi works. Instead use just `foo = bar`.

Comment: BTW why "banish all OOP-related thoughts"? To my mind, thinking of typeclasses as of interfaces (in OOP sense) helps OOP-heads adapt :)

Comment: @9000 I more say this since trying to write Java code structured around a hierarchy of subtypes is just going to result in unreadable/inefficient Haskell. Type class <=> Interfaces is a useful analogy, but like all analogies it fails eventually. Think multi param type classes, type classes without the type as the first argument and similar

Answer (score 2):

Haskell tends to do well with structural subtyping and "HAS-A" relations. The most direct way to inherit Data1 is to use a `newtype`

```
newtype Data2 = Data2 { unData2 :: Data1 }
```

In this case `Data2` is known to be identical to `Data1`. In fact, at compile time `Data2` will be identical to `Data1`. The important part is that `Data2` will have the chance to define entirely unique type class `instances` if it chooses.

Beyond that, you might make `Data1` record in some more complex "inheriting" data type.

```
data DataMore = 
  DataMore { data1         :: Data1
           , otherThing    :: OtherThing
           , somethingElse :: SomethingElse
           }
```

Now, anything that takes a `Data1` as an argument is capable of being trivially extended to take `DataMore`s instead.

```
-- given...
foo :: Data1 -> Data1 -> X

-- we have
fooMore :: DataMore -> DataMore -> X
fooMore dm1 dm2 = foo (data1 dm1) (data1 dm2)
```

Which is a kind of contravariant subtyping.

Comment: While I understand what you're getting at, the way you worded it is a bit dangerous. Haskell does not have subtyping (structural, contravariant, or any other kind).

Comment: I agree with your critique in technicality, but find that there's a meaningful argument to be made for how there's a "kind of" "inheritance" occurring above. I have no attachment to the terminology, though. I just think it's pedagogically useful.

Comment: “In this case Data2 is known to be identical to Data1” Huh? Given some `f :: Data1 -> ()`, one cannot pass a Data2. Unless I’m missing something?

Comment: J's wording is incomplete -- Data2 is *structurally* identical to Data1, meaning they contain isomorphic data, and the compiler will probably use the same bit representations for both types. But you are correct that they're labelled differently and the Haskell type system will not let you mix them up.